# SwiftUI, How to Use Programmatic Navigation Using Value, with different NavigationDestinations

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink, ios16

I am struggling to get my head around how to use programmatic navigation with multiple destination views which take the same type of value.  In the following code I can successfully navigate from ContentView to View2, but would like to navigate from View2 to View3 by adding a value to the path.
The navigationDestination in ContentView has View2 specified.  How/where do I add a second navigationDestination to View3?  If I add a navigationDestination in View2 pointing to View3 then it doesn't work, as it uses the View1's navigationDestination as it is closer to root.  I would appreciate some guidance on how to approach this problem.  Many thanks in advance.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            
            NavigationLink(value: "view2") {
                Text("Go to View2")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { destination in
                View2(someParameterA: destination)
            }
            .navigationTitle("ContentView")
        }
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    @State var someParameterA: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someParameterA)
            NavigationLink(value: "view3") {
                Text("Go to View3")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("View 2")
    }
}
struct View3: View {
    @State var someParameterB: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(someParameterB)
        .navigationTitle("View 3")
    }
}
```

I've managed to hack the following solution together which works but is there a better approach?

```
enum DestinationView {
    case view2
    case view3
}

struct NavStruct: Equatable, Hashable {
    var destinationView: DestinationView
    var param: String
}
class ViewSelector {
    @ViewBuilder
    static func viewForDestination(_ destination: DestinationView, _ param: String) -> some View {
        switch destination {
        case .view2:
            View2(someParameterA: param)
        case .view3:
            View3(someParameterB: param)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            
            NavigationLink(value: NavStruct(destinationView: .view2, param: "view2")) {
                Text("Go to View2")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: NavStruct.self) { destination in
                ViewSelector.viewForDestination(destination.destinationView, destination.param)
            }
            .navigationTitle("ContentView")
        }
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    @State var someParameterA: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someParameterA)
            NavigationLink(value: NavStruct(destinationView: .view3, param: "view3")) {
                Text("Go to View3")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("View 2")
    }
}
struct View3: View {
    @State var someParameterB: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someParameterB)
        }
        .navigationTitle("View 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've managed to hack a working solution but I would like to know if there is a better approach?```